# in which order objective -c blocks will execute?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

i am new to objective C. how blocks will execute ?

```
int c = 10;
int (^blockmethod) (int, int);

blockmethod = ^(int a, int b) { return a+b+c;};

int x = blockmethod (10,11);
c = 11;
int y = blockmethod(10,11);
NSLog(@"%d %d",x,y);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? You've written all the code out already. Also, they execute in the order you'd expect, x then y.

Comment: Blocks don't magically make things asynchronous. They get used in a lot of asynchronous methods, but only because blocks are a good solution to that problem, hence everybody's confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer will be

31 and 31

because blocks are copys environment when they are created thats why
after this,

```
blockmethod = ^(int a, int b) { return a+b+c;};
```

Value of variable c is always 10 for this block.
Even value is changed to 11 but block already copy that variable as 10.

And blocks will be fired in order which you called in order (same like functions)